# How do you focus a class textbox in webkitbrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, webkit, browser

I have this code for putting text into a `textbox` in a website:

Website code:

```
<textarea class="chat_input">

    Enter text for chat here

</textarea>
```

Program Code:

```
message = txtMessage.Text;
foreach(Node txt in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea"))
{
    if(((Element)txt).GetAttribute("Class") == "chat_input")
    {
        ((Element)txt).TextContent = message;
    }
}
```

But the problem is, it only puts the text in when the `textbox` is focused.
Is there any way I can focus the `textbox` so that I don't have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Element.focus method?

I don't know if your webkit binding is exposing that method, but its standard DOM method.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp

Comment: This is the correct answer. I starting working on my program offline, and decided to see if I could find anything that would work, and I found that. Thanks for the answer!